# Why is my application of conservation of momentum in this problem wrong?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum

I'm trying to understand the solution to the following exercise

> The balloon, the light rope and the monkey shown in figure are at rest in the air. If the monkey reaches the top of the rope, by what distance does the balloon descend? We denote the mass of the balloon as $M$, the mass of the monkey as $m$ and the length of the rope as $L$, see also the picture below.

[image]

The answer is $\frac{mL}{m+M}$, but I'm having trouble understanding how to get it. I tried to solve it with the following ansatz using conservation of momentum:

$$0 = \frac{mL}{t} + Mv,$$

reasoning that the time of descent and time taken for monkey to reach the top are both equal to $t$ and $v$ is the velocity of descent.

But to get the correct answer I have to use:

$$0= \frac{mL}{t} + (M+m)v$$

I don't understand why this is correct instead of what I wrote, could anyone explain this?

Comment: I don't see why there are down votes for this.  It may be homework but the OP explained what they tried and asked for help understanding the problem.  That's surely on-topic.

Comment: @StephenG Poor formatting often causes downvotes unrelated to the actual content, in particular if it looks like the formatting often used for blatant "solve this problem for me" questions. I edited it now. Babadadestroyer, have a look at what I did and try to format future questions yourself in a more easily readable format: Don't include giant images one has to scroll past to get to the actual question, use a title that actually tells people what the question is about and typeset formulae using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020).

Comment: Since they are at rest in the air, what momentum are you trying to conserve in the problem? It is a center-of-mass question, not a collision.

Comment: You mean the shift of centre of mass will give me the distance the balloon descends?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should not worry yourself with the exact details of the movement (you assumed constant velocity, and it is not given in the question or necessary-

Try to use conservation of energy instead - What gravitational energy does each of the bodies possess in the beginning and end of the process?

Comment: but the monkey is doing work by climbing.